# Why did I get a 403 after I deployed my Spring+Vue project on the server(tomcat and nginx)？

Tags: java, spring, vue.js, nginx, spring-security

I used SpringMVC+SpringSecurity+Vue to build a project, It works fine in local.But I get a 403 error where try to deploy it on cloud server.

I tried to deploy it on tomcat and nginx,
this is nginx configuration code

```
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/local/website/webapp/dist;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

and there are some code about Spring Security

```
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
       configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8081"));

        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

chrome shows:
'Provisional headers are shown'

Comment: Is there a firewall upstream of the nginx web server? Depending on your cloud provider, there may be a firewall that is blocking port 8081

Comment: @ChrisD'Englere  I don't think so,  I entered 'firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
'  and  It shows ' 3000/tcp 80/tcp 8111/tcp 800/tcp 9001/tcp 8081/tcp 32400/tcp 9000/tcp 8000/tcp 6800/tcp 22/tcp' , so I think 8081 is open.